# How to LinQ statement concatenation in 2 model with condition?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities

I've problem with linq as i need to get 2 result in one row as in model

Model 1 :

```
Public int Id { Get; set}
Public String Name {get; set;}
Public Icollection<Model2> Model2 {get;set;}
```

Model 2 :

```
Public int Id {get ; set}
Public string Path {get; set;}
Public bool IsDone { get;set;}
Public int Model1Id {get; set;}
Public virtual Model1 Model1 {get ; set ;}
```

and i want result like that

Id | Name | pathIsDone | pathIsnotDone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if in `pathIsDone` and `pathIsnotDone` you need counts then:

```
var models1 = .....// your collection of Models1

var result = models1.Select(m1 => new 
    {
        m1.Id,
        m1.Name,
        pathIsDone = m1.Model2
            .Where(m2 => m2.IsDone)
            .Count(),
        pathIsnotDone = m1.Model2
            .Where(m2 => !m2.IsDone)
            .Count(),
    })
    .ToArray();
```